# Render attachments on VIsualforce

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have a donation object which have a donation receipt attached to each record. Now how to render the `receipt.pdf` attachment on visualforce page ? I mean is there any way to query the attachment and show on visualforce as pdf ?

Answer (score 1):

Most common way to do so:

```
<iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!PDF_Doc}" alt="Undable to display pdf" width="100%" height="400px"/>
```

Additional information here:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000044612&language=en_US